# How to get a SQL query on a Snowflake database to return a result set as a table not using stored procedure or UDF

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is more of a how to do question than needing help with code logic or a bug. My Google searches have not been successful in finding an answer.

I have a Nodejs application that connects to a SQL database using connection pools. I have changed my database to Snowflake also using connection pools to connect. My Snowflake SQL query (which is not a stored procedure and not in a UDF) returns the result set as an object and not a table. How can I force Snowflake SQL to return the result set as a table? I saw `rowMode` in the Snowflake documentation but the options that go with it do not produce the results in a table.

Here is an example of my code:

```
await pool.use(async (clientConnection) =>
        {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            clientConnection.execute({
            sqlText: `SELECT * FROM TABLE xyz WHERE USER_ID = ?)`,
            binds: [userId],
            rowMode: 'array',
            complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
                if (err) {
                  console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
                } else {
                  console.log('Successfully executed get user statement: ' + rows.length);
                  result = rows;                                        
                }                       
            }
            })
        })
        });
```

What I want is for the `rows` that get stored in `result` to be in the form of a table to not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the Snowflake's result (rows) into table-like array.
I did not try the following code, but it should be something similar to:

const tableData = rows.map(row => Object.values(row));

// Assuming the first row contains column headers, extracting column names
const columnNames = Object.keys(snowflakeResult[0]);

console.log(columnNames); // Array of column names
console.log(tableData);   // Array of arrays representing rows